# Invalid parameter for sklearn estimator MLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, mlp

Using data from a regression created with `make_regression` from `sklearn.datasets`

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)
```

I am trying to apply Bayesian optimization over hyperparameters in MLPRegressor from  sklearn as shown:

```
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

# Bayesian
n_iter = 100

# MLP regressor
mlpr = MLPRegressor()

param_grid = {
    "activation": ["logistic", "tanh", "relu"],
    "solver": ["lbfgs", "sgd", "adam"],
    "regressor__learning_rate": (0.0001, 0.001, 0.01),
}

reg_bay = BayesSearchCV(estimator=mlpr,
                        search_spaces=param_grid,
                        n_iter=n_iter,
                        cv=5,
                        n_jobs=8,
                        scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                        random_state=123)

model_bay = reg_bay.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

And I got this:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter regressor for estimator MLPRegressor(activation='tanh'). 
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

It doesn't work even though 'tanh' is a function for hidden layer activation. I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this!

Versions:

> sklearn==1.0.1

> python==3.7.14

---

UPDATE:

```
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Bayesian
n_iter = 100

# MLP regressor
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('MLPRegressor', MLPRegressor())
])

param_grid = {
    "MLPRegressor__activation": ["logistic", "tanh", "relu"],
    "MLPRegressor__solver": ["lbfgs", "sgd", "adam"],
    "MLPRegressor__learning_rate": : ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"],
}

reg_bay = BayesSearchCV(estimator=pipe ,
                        search_spaces=param_grid,
                        n_iter=n_iter,
                        cv=5,
                        n_jobs=8,
                        scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                        random_state=123)

model_bay = reg_bay.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

I got:

```
---> model_bay = reg_bay.fit(X_tr, y_tr)

ValueError: Not all points are within the bounds of the space.
```

Comment: For help with debugging, please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also post the version numbers of the libraries you are using.

Comment: The issue seems to be the presence of the `regressor__learning_rate` parameter (if it's commented out, the code runs).  Did you maybe mean to use `learning_rate_init` instead (see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html))?

Comment: I tried using "learning_rate_init" and still the problem persists. When I tried changing to "mlpr__activation", "mlpr__solver" and "mlpr__learning_rate": ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"]. I got: "ValueError: Not all points are within the bounds of the space."